# Accessing Laravel .env variables in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get some API keys which I have stored in my .env file to use in the blade javascript. I have added two keys like:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=////
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_GOOGLE_MAPS=////
APP_OVERHEID_IO=////
```

In blade I need to use the Google Maps API and OverheidIO API key. I have tried getting one of the default .env variables just in case I have formatted the custom .env variables wrong.:

```
{{ env('APP.ENV') }} // nothing
{{ env('APP_ENV') }} // nothing
{{ env('APP_ENV'), 'test' }} // returns 'test'
```

Could someone help me call the google maps api and overheidio api key in the blade?

Comment: Try to run `php artisan config:clear` and test `env('APP_ENV')` in tinker. For me it returns `local` string.

Comment: Thank you Alexey! `php artisan config:clear` did the trick.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, is it not fine if you post your comment as Answer?. I am pretty new to using SO & not very clear about the rules.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev that question is a duplicate of mine, I asked it before...

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) you'll find a discussion about duplicate questions.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, don't take it personally, it is a good question. I voted it up, and gave it an answer. But it is a duplicate.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev the question you flagged as it being a duplicate of was asked after I asked my question, how can this then be a duplicate of that if I asked the question first.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, sorry, I may be wrong, I thought the other question is better stated. But it is not up to me to decide, it is up to community to make a decision, I hope, that people with admin privileges would see situation clearer than me and make a right choice of that is an original and what is a duplicate.

Comment: Attention, env('APP_ENV') will fail in production, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626957/4820095

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Five most important commands if your Laravel is not working as expected after some modifications in .env or database folder or because of any other modifications.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Exactly the reason sometimes, Laravel 5.5 has a hard caching system

Comment: good stuff, but attention, env('APP_ENV') will fail in production, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626957/4820095

Comment: @ndberg that is when you use the command `php artisan config:cache` and I am not using that one. Please read.

Comment: Hi @ndberg I double reviewed your answer to this question (link in the comment above) and you refer to `php artisan config:cache` as @Learner mentions. BUT, I am not sure if Learner's answer needs to be edited to add the missing command, or if you made a mistake. Please, clarify it.

Comment: @Learner is right, he does not use it in his answer and it's not needed. But I just wanted to outline for all googler: usually in production, we use config:cache, and eventually the call as used in the question: "env('APP.ENV')" will bring troubles. So it just was an addition to this answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, there is a reason `env` variables don't work when you have a cache enabled and they'll stop working as soon as you reenable the cache, see below

Answer (score 65):

**VERY IMPORTANT**

All env() like: `env('APP_ENV')` calls **WON'T WORK** in production (when you use `php artisan config:cache`)

What to use?

- use env() only in config files
- use App::environment() for checking the environment (APP_ENV in .env).
- use config('app.var') for all other env variables, ex. config('app.debug')
- create own config files for your own ENV variables. Example:
  In your .env:

  MY_VALUE=foo

example config/myconfig.php

```
return [
    'myvalue' => env('MY_VALUE', 'bar'), // 'bar' is default if MY_VALUE is missing in .env
];
```

Access in your code:

```
config('myconfig.myvalue') // will result in 'foo'
```

---

More details see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393294/4820095)

Comment: What @ndberg says here is key: `use env() only in config files`. This is the best answer to this question.

Comment: I like this answer but I believe there is an small issue. The config files must be placed into the config folder. In this example "config/myconfig.php" must be used instead of "app/myconfig.php"

Comment: You're right, I updated it.

Comment: This answer seems to imply you can't use the `config()` helper to check the environment - why and what's the source for this info?

Comment: Nope, it's no problem to use the config() helper. But you should not use the env() helper outside of config files.

Answer (score 43):

I have it implemented in the following way:

```
@if (env('APP_ENV')!='Production')
Enviroment Test
@endif
```

My recommendation is to execute the following command: `composer self-update`

Comment: This will fail if configuration caching is enabled. Use `config` instead

Comment: Can be written as `@if(App::environment('production'))`

Comment: From Laravel 7.1+, you can use @env(['development','local','etc etc'])   .... @endenv

Comment: The entire question is about why `env('APP_ENV')` isn't working for the OP. Why do you think  putting it in an `if()` statement is going to change that?

Answer (score 23):

You should only access `.env` values directly inside configuration files, then access them from everywhere (controllers, views) from configuration files using `config()` helper

For example:

> .env
>
> ```
> TEST_URL=http://test
> ```

---

> config/app.php
>
> ```
> return [
>    'test_url' => env('TEST_URL','http://default.url')
> ];
> ```

---

> resources/views/welcome.blade.php
>
> ```
> {{ config('app.test_url')}}
> ```
>
> see [configuration caching](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#configuration-caching) from laravel documentation for more info.

Answer (score 15):

Since [Laravel 7.11](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/CHANGELOG-7.x.md#v7110-2020-05-12), you can use the `@env('')` and `@production()` directives in blade templates:

```php
@env('staging')
    // The application is running in "staging"...
@endenv

@env(['staging', 'production'])
    // The application is running in "staging" or "production"...
@endenv
```

or

```php
@production
    // Production specific content...
@endproduction
```

See also in the [Laravel Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements).

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get the environment of the app then try this:

```
{{App::environment()}}
```

I have not tried other variables.

Answer (score 5):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

should fix it

Answer (score 5):

It causes problems to use env() anywhere else than in the config/ folder. Use env in there and then config () in the other parts of the app

Answer (score 5):

get values here: `config/app.php`

in blade:

```
{{ config('app.name', 'default value here') }}
```

in class/controller:

```
config('app.name', 'default value here')
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration

In the sample below, I spit out the actual error when I'm in my development environment but give a generic message if in any other environment.

```
@if(App::environment('development'))
    Error: {{ $record->s_error }}
@else
    XML Parsing Error - Please double check that your file is formatted correctly.
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{{ env('APP_ENV') }}
```

**If It doesn't work then run the below command. It worked for me. You can try. This command will clear the configuration cache. **

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Never use `env()` anywhere in your code, other than inside `config/*.php`

Use `config()` to access default/custom variables in blade files/Controllers.

For example

`config('app.name')`

`config('app.env')`

where `app` is the file name inside the `config` directory.
you can use any file name inside config directory to access the variable inside it.

Although answers by others are right, i found it hard to understand, so finally read the whole documentation for [config](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration) page.

Important comment from documentation.

`Once the configuration has been cached, the .env file will not be loaded; therefore, the env function will only return external, system level environment variables.`

Answer (score 0):

This command should be written after you edit .env file to access variables in easy way

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also having trouble getting value from .env file, then i did this and it helped :

1. Check env file and see if you have given the correct value.
2. then check blade or controller where you using that variable from .env file.
3. if both steps above goes right, you just need to do these steps -

> php artisan config:clear
>   php artisan cache:clear
>   php artisan view:clear
>   php artisan route:clear
>   composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (env('APP_ENV')=='Production')
 do something login,verify etc
else
  do something
```

- Here env('APP_ENV') won't work in production so better to get from
  config folder and make your own file and access that.
- Ex:-config/customconfig.php ->make new file

  env('APP_ENV'),

   ];

and then you can access like this

```
if (config('customconfig.appenv')=='Production')
     do something login,verify etc
    else
      do something
```

- **and final run php artisan config:cache**