# Laravel - accessing .env variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I tried to get the environment variable from the .env in my root with

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "value is". getenv('APP_ENV');
});
```

and

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "it is". env('APP_ENV');
});
```

It is in .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
```

How can I get access to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "it is".config('app.name');
});
```

Answer (score 22):

With Laravel, you should avoid environmental variables outside of your configuration files.

In your config files, you can use environmental variables, example in config/app.php:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

Then you can access this using the config helper: `config('app.env')`.

This allows you to cache your configuration and still access these values, since `env('APP_ENV')` will **no longer work once your config is cached**.
As [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env) mention:

> "If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null`."

Comment: Where you set the otherwise `'production'`, can it be a `'OTHER_ENV_VAR'` as well?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't nest env calls:  `env('APP_ENV', env('OTHER_ENV_VAR', 'ultimate_default'))`

Answer (score 10):

use `env('ENVKEY')`
Don't forget to clear cache sometime it cause because of cache.

```bash
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

For more info look at the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration)

Comment: Application cache wouldn't affect environmental variables, only config cache.

Comment: maybe not, but something it doesn't work.  There are many case for example u can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accessing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade

Comment: That's fine, but the only thing relevant is your first command.  I suggest you research the other two commands if you think they are relevant to this question.

Comment: I do think it's relevant therefor I added so. Thank you for ur info though i ll research on it

Comment: thanks for this took me 1hr to figure it out. new for laravel config

Answer (score 2):

just run this commands in cmd.

> php artisan config:cache

then

> php artisan config:clear

then

> php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 1):

laravel provides a global helper function for this kind of task

```
$val = config('app.something');
```

you can also set new values with the following method

```
config(['app.something' => 'cat']);
```

[reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration)

for your particular task it would be

```
$val = config('app.env');
```

or to determine the env globally

```
$environment = App::environment();
```

i hope this helps, have a nice one!

Comment: This is empty Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "Environment ". config('APP_ENV');
}); do i have to set it somewhere else?

Comment: How about in Javascript (blade file)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Laravel Documentation on [Environment Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration),

> All of the variables listed in this file will be loaded into the $_ENV
>   PHP super-global when your application receives a request. You may use
>   the env helper to retrieve values from these variables.

So, it is possible to access the variable as

```
$_ENV['envKey'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 App::environment()
```

try this please

Comment: I have tried env('APP_ENV'), $_ENV('APP_ENV') but results null. 
This function gives me the result. cheers :)