# Laravel Method does not exist after rename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a little problem here after I renamed a method from **store** to **save** also I was renamed in the *Route*

```
Route::post('blog', 'Backend\BlogController@store');
```

to

```
Route::post('blog', 'Backend\BlogController@save');
```

but when I hit submit it still shows me:

> Method [store] does not exist.

anyone can help me out?

Comment: Clear any caches, then if that doesn't sort it, search your code base for `store`.

Comment: still not working, i've been clear all caches with `php artisan route:clear` and search in `App` directory but didn't found match with 'store' ... any solution ?

Comment: Can you please tell me if by any chance you've used Resource Route like this `Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Apparently, my mistake is put `"route :: resource"` at the **bottom**, then I just deleted it.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command.

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

if the problem persists, please use below commands also

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: still not working, but when i tried to renamed the method again to `store` it's working again ... though `store` doesn't appear in `Route`

Comment: You can try below commands to solve the problem.

**php artisan optimize** 
, 
**php artisan cache:clear** 
, 
**php artisan route:cache** 
, 
**php artisan view:clear** 
, 
**php artisan config:cache**

Answer (score 2):

Just run this command for Clear Route cache: `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Clear your laravel cache using this command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Accessing Laravel .env variables in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accessing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade/43041479#43041479)

for detail list of commands to resolve any kind of cache issues as this one.