# How to import varibales from a .env file to index.html html page

Tags: html

I have a .env file including following data:

```
DB_PORT=49500
APP_NAME=Python
APP_HTTP_PORT=49502
APP_HTTPS_PORT=49503
```

I want to use these variables in my index.html page like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>**$APP_NAME** - Summary Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
```

How to use the variables from other file which is a .env file into my index.html page?

Comment: Using what server side language/setup? This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040967/6083675

Comment: Not possible: HTML can't do that - it's a markup language, so you'll need some preprocessing to insert insert these variables, like Jinja.

Comment: @Laurel  I am using html page to display normally the contents of the page. I just want the variables I use in that page to be replaced by the values which will come from .env file

Comment: @KanikaKohli — And you need to use a programming language to do that replacement. So step 1 is picking a programming language.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `PHP` to read the `.env` file and return those values to `JavaScript` (if wanted).

```php
$filename = "your_env_file.env";
$file = fopen($filename, "r") or die("500 Server Error: Can't open file.");
$content = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$info = array();
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $data = explode("=", $line);
    $info[$data[0]] = rtrim($data[1], "\r");
}
$json_encoded_info = json_encode($info); // to send to JavaScript
/*
 * Now we can echo the $info array to the HTML with
 * echo $info;
 *
 * or we can send JS the variables using
*/

echo "<script>
var info = JSON.parse(\"".$json_encoded_info."\");
//Do something with the info here
</script>";

/*
 * Unfortunately, this shows all of your .env information in the string.
 * A better way is with AJAX.
 * See link reference below for more ways to do this.
 */
```

[How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549)

What this code does is:

1. Read all of the content of your `.env` file
2. Split all of the lines
3. Put all of the line information into `$info`

The comments explain what you can do with that information (echo to HTML, send to Javascript).

Looking at your question, it seems like you want to replace `**APP_NAME**` with its respective value.  You can use `Javascript` to obtain the value from `PHP` (it should be Python in this case) through one of the methods in [the linked Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549), and then replace `**APP_NAME**` (or whatever other key you want) with the value received from `PHP`.