# Issue in accessing server key from env (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have my server key in .env on production but sometimes notification stops working as server key not accessable .

But when I run the command **php artisan config:cache** then it again starts working .

Comment: what do you mean by server key?

Comment: server key from firebase which is used to send notifications

Comment: I am in development and accessing in this way
$SERVER_API_KEY = env('SERVER_KEY','0');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Laravel .env variables in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accessing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not access the variable of .env directly in controller or inside any file. First you have to access that variable in any config file.
Like below:

For e:g; inside config/app.php define your server key
`'server_key' => env('server_key')`

after defining above key in config/app.php you have to access it inside any file as below:
`config('app.server_key')`

By doing this you will permanantly resolve your issue.