# get env varaible with script jquery

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I´m trying to get one variable from my .env in Laravel 5.8, but it always returns a string.

```
{!! getenv("RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY") !!}
```

I have this code:

```
e.preventDefault();
key = '{!! getenv("RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY") !!}';

console.log(key);
```

I also tried:

```
e.preventDefault();
key = '{{ env("RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY") }}';
    
console.log(key);
```

But I always get the same result. I need to do this to generate google Recaptcha with jQuery and Ajax when I click on my login or register button. How I can to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the laravel .env variables inside javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683562/how-to-access-the-laravel-env-variables-inside-javascript)

Comment: @Indra not... returned for me a syntax error.

Comment: check the answers there. one of those is right for you. Please remove your question since it's a duplicate

Comment: @Indra i check this question and always returned a string "{{ env("RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY") }}" not my key

Comment: @daviserraalonso Did you try use `key = '{{ env('RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY') }}';` instead `key = '{{ env("RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY") }}';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try...

```
<script>

    let key = '{{ config('RECAPTCHAV3_SITEKEY') }}';

    alert(key);

</script>
```