# How in resources/js/app.js get APP_DEBUG from .env file?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 / alpinejs 3 application in resources/js/app.js file
I use https://github.com/harunurhan/idlejs to
logout on some idle period of time.

But I want to set different period of time depending on APP_DEBUG in .env file.

I tried several ways described here :
[How to access the laravel .env variables inside javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683562/how-to-access-the-laravel-env-variables-inside-javascript)

But none of them work for me.

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seeing how you tagged this laravel then take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables . In short you can add another environment variable like `MIX_APP_DEBUG=${APP_DEBUG}` and use that one instead. Beware that all environment variables you expose to MIX will be visible in the browser so never reveal any server variables

Comment: "*none of them work for me*" - why not? Errors? There is no magic to using PHP vars in JS, and the question you linked to describes many valid options. Why don't they work?